# How can I pass the result of a function as a default value of another function?

Tags: php

I have a function that is called without the user giving notice, and it just creates a row on my Database.
The function is this one:

```
public function createRow($year = 2015) {
    $query = DB::table('myTable')->where('year', '=', $year)->get()->first();
    // The rest of the function doesn't matter
}
```

The problem here is that I need the default value for this function to be the year before the actual year. In order to do that I tried to put this:

```
public function createRow($year = date('Y') - 1) {
    $query = DB::table('myTable')->where('year', '=', $year)->get()->first();
    // whatever
}
```

It's obvious it didn't work, so I did a really small function that return the year before the actual year, and I tried to use the result of the small function as the default parameter of the `createRow()` function:

```
public function lastYear() {
   return date('Y') - 1;
}
public function createRow($year = $this->lastYear()) {
    $query = DB::table('myTable')->where('year', '=', $year)->get()->first();
    // Whatever
}
```

I also tried defining a global variable:

```
protected $lastYear = date('Y') - 1;
```

but I got the error:

> expression is not allowed as field default value

I hope you can help me with this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function createRow($year = null) {
    if ($year == null)
    {
        $year = date('Y') - 1;
    }
    $query = DB::table('myTable')->where('year', '=', $year)->get()->first();
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely forgot that. Thanks for reminding me that. That was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function createRow($year) {

    if (!$year)
    {
        $year = date('Y') - 1;
    }

    $query = DB::table('myTable')->where('year', '=', $year)->get()->first();
    // whatever
}
```

You can change the if condition so if $year does not contain a valid value you can set the it the default value in the beginning of the function.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know I could do that. It's really good to have other options. Thanks again.